# language_check Remote end closed connection without response issue

Tags: python, django, languagetool

I'm using [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check) python package in one of my Django projects.

I've installed it using `pip install --upgrade language-check` command. It was working fine in my device. Then I've hosted the project to an AWS ec2 instance. When I try to use the package it gives me to the following error :

> language_check.Error: http://127.0.0.1:8081: Remote end closed
>   connection without response

And this is my inbound rules :

[image]

How can I solve the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading JRE version to 8 and installing the `language-check` package as `root` user did the trick for me.